# Best .php CMS for handling ad-hoc product quotes

Tags: php, content-management-system, cart, e-commerce, quote

I am developing a new e-commerce enabled site for a company that sells two types of products which I will call: (1) widget items, which are minimally customizable, and (2) cars, which are highly customizable (so complex that CMS's I have reviewed, including Magento, OpenCart, etc. can't handle them with default functionality).  I have already written the scripts to handle type (2) customisations, which I will need to integrate into whichever CMS I choose.

For type (2) products, customers will create their customized product, and then request a quote.  My client will then input a price online, and then the client can add the quote/price combination to his/her cart if s/he chooses.  The quote number plus a small description of the unique product/project would be added to the cart, instead of static product attributes as with type (1).

**My question** is whether there is a cart (or cart + extensions) out there that can handle both type (1) and type (2) products.  That is, one that can have both static price and quoted price items put in the same cart.  If there is not, which .php CMS would you recommend I develop this functionality in?

I have explored Magento, Drupal + Unbercart, CMS MS w/ its products + modules, OpenCart, and even wordPress.  I'm leaning towards Drupal + Ubercart for its sheer flexibility/extensibility, but have reservations about its reputation for slow performance.  My client doesn't host on a dedicated server, so performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend testing ZOO 2.x for Joomla. It's an extremly flexible CCK which you can use to build customizable items. You will have to get into ZOO, but the apps which are shipping with ZOO are a good start. Only thing is that ZOO is not a eCommerce Extension, so you will have to add a cart feature and payment prozessors if you need them.